# How to grab sentences separated by dashes

Tags: python, regex, csv

What regular expression would grab the sentences (representing speech) if they are separated by a dash? The problem is that sometimes such senteces are inserted in normal sentences and are hence set off by dashes on both sides. But other times they are opened with a dash and closed with a full-stop. More so that dashes are not always used for setting off the spoken sentences. The parts that I need to capture are put in the brackets (sorry, the sentences are in Lithuanian).

```
[- Dilze, -] šaukė ji be jokios intonacijos, pabrėžtinumo ar skubos, tarsi nesitikėdama atsakymo. [- Dilze!]
Dilzė atsakė ir liovės barškinusi rykais, stovinčiais ant krosnies, bet dar nespėio pereit per virtuvę, kai ponia Kompson pašaukė dar kartą, o kol ji perėjo per valgomąjį ir kyštelėjo galvą į tą pilką lango šviesą, - dar vieną kartą.
[- Einu, einu, -] atsakė Dilzė. [- Aš čia. Pripilsiu ją, kai tik vanduo sušils, -] pasikaišė sijoną ir ėmė kopti laiptais, visai užstodama tą pilką šviesą. [- Padėkit ją antžemės ir grįžkite į lovą.]
```

Comment: Which language or tool are you using? And what have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

In Python `re` does not support Unicode character properties, but [`regex`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex) does.

Use `regex.findall` with pattern

```
(?m)-\s*\p{Lu}.*?(?:-|[.,!?]\s*$)
```

Comment: I have edited your question to include the programming language. In the future, please include this in your original question so that people have a better chance of helping you.

Comment: @Omega, I'm a very very beginner in both Python and etc. Would the code look like this?import re

filename="C:/Users/.../LITH.txt"
fileobj=open(filename, "r")
ptext=fileobj.read()
fileobj.close()
pat= ur'-\s*\p{Lu}.*?(?:-|[.,!?]\s*$)'
m=re.compile(pat,re.MULTILINE | re.UNICODE)

print m

Comment: @gabrielemucho - You cannot use Unicode character property with `re`. Use module regex (http://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex) >> `regex.findall(r"(?m)-\s*\p{Lu}.*?(?:-|[.,!?]\s*$)", input)`

Comment: It returns: no module named regex

Comment: @gabrielemucho - I have provided a link to this module in my answer, as well as in the previous comment, so if you don't have it installed, download it from that site and install it. I am sorry, but I think there is nothing more I can do for you. You have to install the module by yourself...

Answer (score -1):

As I understand you are looking for a regex that matches anything that starts with `[-` and ends with `.]` where the dot can be any line-ending.

The regex `\[\-.*?[\-\.\!]\]` does this. The part `[\-\.\!]` define all the characters that can prefix the ending `]`. The questionmark in the middle makes sure that the regex isn't greedy, but it is regex-implementation specific if this will work for you.

Comment: I see now that I expected your brackets to be in your text.
`\-.*?[\-\.\!]` should work.

Comment: Yes, I'm looking for a regex. But it does not necessarily ends with .]. It always starts with [-, but could end with these 4 options: ,-] or .] or !] or ?]

Comment: Hi Martijn, this one \-.*?[\-\.\!] is as good as to grab the very first instance in the text but does not grab other strings :(.

Comment: Then `\[\-.*?[\-\.\!\?]\]` is a possible regex. 
To answer your second problem: There are several possible uses for the regex. Using a function which only returns the first result is one of them. There is most likely another function which returns all found results.

Answer (score -1):

I like to use string manipulation rather than regex in cases with brackets.

```
>>> text = '''[- here is some text -] here is some not text [- that i want to get -]'''

>>> [sent.split('-]')[0] for sent in text.split('[-') if '-]' in sent]
[' here is some text ', ' that i want to get ']
```

`text.split('[-')` splits over the string `[-`.  List comprehension feeds those results into a second split, splitting on the opposing bracket.  Note, this will not work if you have 'floating' brackets, but it's a good, cheap (regex is expensive) solution if you're manipulating markups that someone put in by hand.  This way, you don't have to worry about installing a module.